# JAVA.Eclipse - How to solve "Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder""

Tags: slf4j

I'm learning Selenium with Eclipse-JAVA.
I started my first code to open GMAIL browser and I get an error:
**SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.**

I copied the **SLF4J Simple Binding** dependency with the latest 1.7.36 (mvnrepository.com)
and I added to the pom.xml (below) and I get error: "**invalid element name - dependency**"
I'm lost and don't know where to add it or need to do something else. **Thanks!!!**

**pom.xml**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SeleniumTutorial</groupId>
  <artifactId>SeleniumTutorial</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>maven</name>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
      
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>14</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>    
    
    
  </build>
  
  
  
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.36</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
</project>
```

***my code:***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Selenium//Drivers//chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.gmail.com");
        driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Download this one: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.31.0/geckodriver-v0.31.0-win64.zip
Need to paste it to the root of my project - Right click on your project name and paste the exe file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).